# Chrome not working after installation of JDK

Tags: windows, google-chrome, java-8, windows-10

I installed jdk-8u101-windows-x64 on my Windows 10 x64 in order to proceed with installing a Netbeans 8.1 all in one package, and after JDK was installed the system immediately restarted.

When the system rebooted, Chrome stopped working. Loading any page or even settings page now displays "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this web page. Learn more - Reload".

Clicking Learn more or reloading does nothing. I tried disabling Defender and enabling again, didn't work.

Reinstalling, or restarting the PC multiple times didn't work.

Has anyone come across this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have EMET running on your machine? I recently had the same thing happen. Something caused me to reboot, and as a side effect, chrome got updated to a version with this bug introduced in chrome 53 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=643775

Comment: please add a screenshot of the browser settings and the extensions

Comment: What is EMETE? I cannot provide a screenshot, since I'm unable to open the settings, as suggested in the post above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have a Windows 10 x64 OS and just tried installing the JDK. It was JDK 8 Update 101 and my Google Chrome version is 53.0.2785.143. It did not force me to restart but I went ahead and restarted and when I booted back up I did not see the same issues that you were referring to.

[image: screenshots]

This leads me to believe that it's something specific with your machine and nothing with the JDK or Chrome itself. It's possible that you have some chrome extension that is causing problems.

To fix the issue you're having first I would download and install the [Chrome Cleanup Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/). If that doesn't fix the issue, you can try launching Chrome in 'safe-mode' like so:

> Right Click, create shortcut, rename, right click go to properties and add - -incognito- with out the - in the target field on shortcut tab. Then apply and ok
>
> [image: properties of chrome shortcut]

Once you are able to launch Chrome in incognito mode, then you should be able to delete the extensions via the settings.

If that still doesn't work, then you will likely have to delete the user data for Chrome in your AppData and registry manually. To delete your AppData go to:
`C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` and delete the Default folder then relaunch Chrome.

To remove the extensions from the registry, Open regedit and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions` and delete the keys there.

Comment: Believe it or not, the issue has resolved by itself with the new Windows 10 update...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like broken Java libraries...

Try uninstalling Netbeans, JDK, Chrome, in that order.
Then installing Chrome again, try it out, then JDK, try Chrome, then Netbeans, try Chrome.

Also check that you have 32bit JDK and that your preferred Java is set to 32bit since Chrome is 32bit.

Comment: Believe it or not, the issue has resolved by itself with the new Windows 10 update...

Comment: @anuga, why would you think so? Chrome doesn't run on JVM